# Is there a placeholder for doubles in Swift?

Tags: swift, double

I want to be able to call various doubles from a collection but I'm having trouble setting it up.

" " can be used on the right side of a value/constant declaration as a placeholder for string values, is there a way to do the same for doubles? I Googled but wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: You shouldn't think of `""` as a placeholder for `String`s either, you know. Why do you need a "placeholder" in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper, correct. But if you want to invalidate an operation if a particular value wasn't set, but do so without an optional, you could use .nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For original question

A "nan" "not a number" has a specific meaning of an undefined or unrepresentable number. There are quiet and signaling versions. You can get a nan by multiplying Double.infinity by something.

```
let alarmTriggeringNotANumber: Double = .signalingNan
let quietNotANumber: Double = .nan
let hero: Double = .zero
let loveLife: Double = -.infinity
```

Technically, `""` isn't a placeholder, but an empty collection. Nil would be a way to indicate the absence of a value.

## For the separate question in the comment

> I want to get a bunch of latitude and longitude coordinates
> and call them from a collection using one name. For example `var latitude = x`, where `x` would represent whichever object I call to it.

You can create a Dictionary/Set where the element is of type Coordinates.

```
struct Coordinates {
 let lat: Double
 let long: Double
}

let batCavesByCountryID: [UUID : [Coordinates]]
```

You can create a type alias that allows you to reference a tuple with a specific signature.

You can also create a typealias for Lat/Long.

Typealiases are useful to reduce code maintenance. For example, you might change IDs from UUIDs to Strings. Using a typealias can be more expressive and let you change a whole app with one line of code. However, going overboard will just make this obscure. You can add extensions to type aliases, but tuples are currently not extendable.

```
typealias Coordinates = (lat: Latitude, long: Longitude)
typealias Latitude = Double
typealias Longitude = Double
```

Comment: I must ask though, as a (perhaps) beginner given a new account, why do you need a placeholder more exotic than zero?

Comment: Placeholder may have been the wrong word. I want to get a bunch of latitude and longitude coordinates and call them from a collection using one name. For example var latitude = x, where x would represent whichever object I call to it.

Comment: Your description leaves it a little unclear what exactly is needed, but I'll update the answer with some options.

Comment: @ILoveChickenWings Just used .isNan today for using the output of an inverse tan function. There's your useless fact of the day.